# Files access/modified in a process/script

Tags: bash, scripts

I will be getting some shell scripts that I, kind of, dont know what they will be doing. But I need to know what **I/O operations** the script performs (e.g. files they read/access,files they write, folders created...etc).

An example is using *strace* as follows:

**INPUT script:** `g++ -Wall a.cpp -o hello`

**I will run it as:** `sudo strace -f -e trace=open g++ -Wall a.cpp -o hello 2> output.txt`

**WHAT I WANT: ** output.txt will have the trace and which files had been accessed (a.cpp and b.h which is used in a.cpp, and output hello)

```
... 
[pid 13871] open("a.cpp", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_LARGEFILE) = 3 
[pid 13871] open("b.h", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_LARGEFILE) = 4 
... 
[pid 13874] open("hello", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_LARGEFILE, 0666) = 3
...
```

**Problem**

1- `strace` doesnt handle *pipe* so if I get a command like `mkdir d2 | cp *.c d2/` it will only detect the first command `mkdir d2`.

2- `strace` provide too much info which is fine but if something is more concrete that would be great!

I searched for other tools and utils, and most of them would list info for a *running process* and I **dont want that** since the script will be executed immediately and nothing would be in the process list in Ubuntu.

Any ideas on how can I achieve this in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding problem 1,

the reason is that `strace` doesn't start the process with a shell, for security reasons.

To fix this, you need to wrap the pipe in `bash -c ' ... '`, replacing `bash` with your shell:

```
sudo strace -f -e trace=open bash -c 'mkdir d2 | cp *.c d2/' hello 2> output.txt
```